# Mathematical Logic: If I don’t have to show something, why is it always correct?

Tags: logic

Let’s assume I have to show it for every element of my set. But when my set is empty, it is right. How can we say that this is true, because I could also say I had to show nothing, so it has to be false. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). Don't forget that if you start with wrong premises, the conclusion can be true or false (see truth table for implication).

Comment: Yeah thank you agree, but why can we say it is false? be cause to say there are elements would be false ?

Comment: Basically the result is undetermined. "If the pope comes to my house, I will be king". As the pope does not come into my house (empty set), we don't know what would happen if he really came, so the result can be true or false.